# PDF certificate is null syncfusion component

Tags: c#, pdf-generation, syncfusion

I am using syncfusion component for Word to PDF conversion and then apply signature on pdf file from PDF.pfx file provided by syncfusion.
Here is code reference:

Open PDF document and apply signature:

```
PdfLoadedDocument document = new PdfLoadedDocument("WordtoPDF8.pdf");
PdfLoadedPage page = document.Pages[0] as PdfLoadedPage;

//Creates a signature field.

PdfSignatureField signatureField = new PdfSignatureField(page, "SignatureField");

        signatureField.Bounds = new RectangleF(0, 0, 100, 100);

        signatureField.Signature = new PdfSignature(document, page, new PdfCertificate(@"C:\Users\someUser\AppData\Local\Syncfusion\EssentialStudio\14.4.0.15\Common\Data\PDF\PDF.pfx", "syncfusion"), "SignatureField");

        signatureField.Signature.Reason = "I am author of this document";

        //Adds the field.

        document.Form.Fields.Add(signatureField);

        //Saves the certified PDF document.



        document.Save();
        //Closes the document
        document.Close(true);
```

Now opening the document and read the signature using following code:

```
 PdfLoadedDocument loadedDocument = new PdfLoadedDocument("WordtoPDF8.pdf");

        //Gets the page of the document

        PdfLoadedPage page1 = loadedDocument.Pages[0] as PdfLoadedPage;

        //Gets the signature field from the PDF document
        PdfLoadedField field = null;;
        loadedDocument.Form.Fields.TryGetField("syncfusion",out field);
        PdfLoadedSignatureField field2 = loadedDocument.Form.Fields[0] as PdfLoadedSignatureField;

        //Get PDF Certificate instance from signature field

        PdfCertificate certificate2 = field2.Signature.Certificate;

        //Get the certificate details

        string subjectName = certificate2.SubjectName;
        string issuerName = certificate2.IssuerName;
```

The problem which I am getting is that the certificate2 is null when I get it. I can't figure out where is the problem. Help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The support for retrieving the certificate details from the existing signed PDF document has been provided recently i.e., from v16.4.0.42 onwards. Kindly refer the below link to download latest essential studio.

https://www.syncfusion.com/forums/141547/essential-studio-2018-volume-4-release-v16-4-0-42-is-available-for-download

Please check with the above latest version to resolve the PdfCertificate null issue.
Note: I work for Syncfusion.

Regards,
Dilli babu.

Comment: Glad I am talking to someone at syncfusion. I have checked and verified that certificate information is there now. But there is not much information. Can you please tell that how I can know that either the document was changed or tempered after the signature was added using syncfusion. 
Thanks.

Comment: Currently we don’t have a support to validate the digital signature for signed PDF and we do not have any immediate plans to implement this feature. Regards -